# IncompatibleClassChangeError in GCM Client Manager of Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I got the crash in my running application with error of `IncompatibleClassChangeError`, I didn't change anything in my code. It started crashing at

```
  InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getContext());
  regid = instanceID.getToken(projectNumber, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

I've tried many solutions to resolve it. Android Studio asked me to change gradle version for `google-play services` I changed into `9.0.1` but no result even it created a new error which is like [image]

Now, I'm not getting any solution that's why I'm putting a question here.

Comment: Could you add the dependencies you are using in your build.gradle file?